# Presuure inside a current carrying wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields

There is a  uniformly distributed throughout its cross section current carrying straight infinite wire. Current is flowing perpendicular to its cross section along its axis.Pressure due to the current at a distance r from its axis will be (r is less than than its radius)
I am stuck in finding current in formula IBL.How can I define current using  current area density J for a elemental strip (parallel to axis) at a distance r. What is the final equation for this que ?

Comment: Use Maxwell stress tensor: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_stress_tensor

Answer (score 0):

First, solve for the B field in the wire (if current is constant, the
current density will be uniform, and most wire is cylindrical).
Second, note that each element of the cross section is a wire, carrying
some current, in a magnetic field.   So, there's a Lorentz force on
that wire element, current  crossproduct with B, toward the center of the entire wire.

One would normaly assume atmospheric pressure on the exterior
of the wire.   Integrate from the exterior surface to get
the force on any interior element, with the atmospheric pressure
being your constant of integration...

The integral will be over R, with dR d(theta), but that
d(theta) doesn't get integrated; when you compute force per
unit area == pressure, it cancels out.

Comment: What would be the final equation be before integration?